# Bot Framework - Dynamic FormFlow Depending on previous Answers

Tags: c#, botframework

I am a bit stuck on this, don't even know if it is entirely possible. Searching the web I came across posts like this one by Joe Mayo: http://mayoster.blogspot.com.es/2016/05/dynamic-formflow-forms-in-bot-builder.html where he explains how to use Dynamic Fields instead of pre-defined enums.

So far so good, the real question comes when the values are not "defined somewhere", but instead depend on a previous answer of the FormFlow. Is this possible? (Considering that the Form Build is done all at once?

Example:

```
public static IForm<ItemQueue> BuildForm()
    {

        return new FormBuilder<ItemQueue>()                
            .Field(nameof(ItemQueue.ItemFamily))
            .Field(nameof(ItemQueue.ItemType))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<ItemQueue>(nameof(ItemGroup))
                .SetType(null)
                .SetDefine((state, field) =>
                {
                    List<string> groupList= GetItemGroups(//PREVIOUS ANSWER HERE);

                    foreach (var group in groupList)
                        field
                             .AddDescription(module, module)
                             .AddTerms(module, module);
                    return Task.FromResult(true);

                }))
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Build()
            ;
    }
```

Where the "//PREVIOUS ANSWER HERE" part determines the zone were the string should be loaded. Tried everything I could think of and searched around with no success, mostly because it is executed as a single step.

Based on some opinions apparently one option is to, after I get the answer I want, start a new FormFlow with the stored value, but does not seem like the cleanest way to do this.

I really appreciate any help on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

Ends up that you can go for the state of the previous fields and send that (as a string, for example) to a new function:

```
public static IForm<ItemQueue> BuildForm()
{

    return new FormBuilder<ItemQueue>()                
        .Field(nameof(ItemQueue.ItemFamily))
        .Field(nameof(ItemQueue.ItemType))
        .Field(new FieldReflector<ItemQueue>(nameof(ItemGroup))
            .SetType(null)
            .SetDefine((state, field) =>
            {
                List<string> groupList= GetItemGroups(state.ItemType.ToString());

                foreach (var group in groupList)
                    field
                         .AddDescription(module, module)
                         .AddTerms(module, module);
                return Task.FromResult(true);

            }))
        .AddRemainingFields()
        .Build()
        ;
}
```

However, you have to beware the fact that the value will only be "usable" for the next field (if it exists) after it enters the {Get; Set;}. Otherwise it will remain null.

That is, in my example I can get *ItemType* Value because, before executing the *ItemGroup* Field it already defined the value for the previous one.

Outside of the **.Field** overrides, if you want to call it **.OnCompletion** you have to do it from the "field" property.